# Solution with different project and shared configSections

Tags: c#, share, configuration-files

I have a solution with three projects.

- Project1 (Windows Application)
- Project2 (Windows Application)
- Project3 (Class Library)

Project1 and Project2 have their own app.config files with appSettings. Now I want the add some appSettings in the Project3. But I don't want the write the new settings in both app.config files. I want a new configfile/section for my shared solution.
How can I create my own config file in Project3 and reference from Project1 and Project2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<appSettings configSource="shared.config">
</appSettings>
```

Then in `shared.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="foo" value="bar" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: In project1 and project2 are already an appSettings section. With your example I would create a second appSettings section and would get an error or I'm wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can only have on appSettings section per project. This is severely limiting and might not suit your intended use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. It's not perfect, but it's working:

1. Create a share.config in Project3

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
> <shareConfig
>   config1="value1">
> </shareConfig>
> ```

2. Create a ShareConfig.cs file in your Project3

> ```
> public class ShareConfig : ConfigurationSection
> {
>     [ConfigurationProperty("config1", IsRequired = true)]
>     public string Config1
>     {
>         get { return (string)base["config1"]; }
>         set { base["config1"] = value; }
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Add the config File as a Link the Project1 and Project2
4. Add the following code in your app.config (Project1 and Project2):

> ```
> <configSections>
>        <section name="shareconfig" type="[classname],  [projectname], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
>     </configSections>
>     <shareconfig configSource="App.Share.config"/>
> ```

5. Now you can use your new config Section like this:

> ```
> ShareConfig config = (ShareConfig )ConfigurationManager.GetSection("shareConfig ");
> ```